# Java JGit API : How to update git submodule?

Tags: java, git, jgit

I'm trying to update the git submodule using Java JGit, so that it points to the latest remote commit.

Please refer the below code snippet and results observed.

Could anyone please help getting the code corrected or provide me an alternate approach. 
Thanks in advance.

```
File parentWorkingDir= 
parentGit.getRepository().getDirectory().getAbsoluteFile();

try (Git git = Git.open(new File(parentWorkingDir,
"modules/submodulePath"))) {
 PullCommand command = git.pull();  //<- Try 1
 // PullCommand command = 
 // git.pull()setRemoteBranchName("refs/heads/branchName"); <- Try 2
 command.setCredentialsProvider(new 
 UsernamePasswordCredentialsProvider(userID, 
 String.valueOf(userPassword)));
 PullResult pullResult = command.call();
 MergeResult mergeResult = pullResult.getMergeResult();
 return mergeResult.getMergeStatus();
}
```

Actual Output:

Try 1 -> Cannot checkout from unborn branch

Try 2 -> pullResult.getMergeResult(); returns null and it ends up with NullpointerException

Expected Outptu:

Should be able to get the merge status and the submodule should get updated/point to the latest commit similar to remote.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this article](https://www.codeaffine.com/2014/04/16/how-to-manage-git-submodules-with-jgit/) you update a submodule by opening a separate Git repository, doing the pull like you tried and then commit the change in the parent Git repository:

```
  File workDir = parent.getRepository().getWorkTree();
  Git libModule = Git.open( new F‌ile( workDir, "modules/library" ) );
  libModule.pull().call();
  libModule.close();
  parent.add().addF‌ilepattern( "modules/library" ).call();
  parent.commit().setMessage( "Update submodule" ).call();
```